# How to Enable or disable Button in ListView MultiDetailRightButtonItem Delphi

Tags: android, listview, delphi, firemonkey

I have a ListView firemonkey and the ItemAppearance.ItemAppearance: = 'MultiDetailRightButtonItem'

I need in certain situations to enable or disable the button at runtime, but I can not.

How to access proprovities of the listview's multidetail objects at application runtime.

I was able to change the ItemAppearance.ItemAppearance: = 'MultiDetailRightButtonItem' to ItemAppearance.ItemAppearance: = 'MultiDetailItem' however the button goes without the Text property, and I could not access it put the Text again.

Marcio

Comment: You can access some of the object's properties at runtime with   <ListView>.ItemAppearanceObjects.ItemObjects... you can reach the Accessory, Text and GlyphButton (if in EditMode). But of these you can just access some properties, like Visible. There is no Enabled property.

Answer (score 1):

If List is your Listview, you can use the property

`List.Items[i].Objects.textbutton.Enabled := false`

to disable or use the property.visible to hide the button.
There are other properties you can find under List.Items[i].Objects.